# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when calling ionic cordova build --release android

Tags: ionic-framework

I've been getting this error message whenever I try to use the 
`ionic cordova build --release android`:

> (node:1512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:1512) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning accures when you call a promise and doesnt add a catch block to it. The catch block gets called when the promise call gets rejected.

for example:

```
var foo = function () {
    fooPromise
        .then(function (res) {
            // Do something with the response of the promise
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // handle the error 
        });
};
```

Check the Javascript Documentation for more information: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)